# module inside if in verilog

Tags: if-statement, verilog

i'm not that much in verilog
i'm trying to call a module inside if statement
i can't find the answer in google or may i didn't understand what should i do with MY CODE

my code is a full adder addition 
i need the IF cause i want to add other things

this is my code:

```
module top (a,b,cin,Cout,Ctemp,sum,clk,X);
input [3:0] a,b;
input  X;
input cin,clk;
output reg[3:0] sum;
output reg[2:0] Ctemp;
output  reg Cout;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
generate
if (X==1)
add bit0(a[0], b[0], cin,  sum[0], Ctemp[0]); //here i need to call add module
add bit1(a[1], b[1], Ctemp[0], sum[1], Ctemp[1]);
add bit2(a[2], b[2], Ctemp[1], sum[2], Ctemp[2]);
add bit3(a[3], b[3], Ctemp[2], sum[3], Cout);
end
endgenerate
endmodule

module add(a, b, cin, sum, cout); 
input  a; 
input  b;
input  cin;
output sum;
output cout;
assign sum = (~a*~b*cin)+(~a*b*~cin)+(a*~b*~cin)+(a*b*cin);
assign cout = (a*b)+(a*cin)+(b*cin);
endmodule
```

Comment: You cannot use a `generate` block inside an `always` block. You do not "call" modules, you "instantiate" them, and you cannot instantiate a model inside an `always` block.

Comment: So my work is mostly wrong :/ .. Thank u @Greg

Answer (score 1):

I'll give some hints. you need to move the module instantiations outside the `always` block (above or below). Then add additional `wire` declarations for for the outputs of the module that you will be flopping. I recommend modifying your module instantiation port connections to explicit (connect-by-name) instead of implicit (connect-by-order). This way even of the port order changes, the connectivity will be maintained. Extremely useful for modules with a lot of ports. 
The body of your top module should looks something like this:

```
// ...
add bit3( .a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .cin(Ctemp[2]),  .sum(pre_sum[3]), .cout(pre_cout));
always@(posedge clk)
begin
  if (X==1) begin
    sum <= pre_sum;
    Cout <= pre_cout;
  end
end
```

Other recommendation: Use ANSI style module header; it is less typing and easier to maintain. Non-ANSI style was required for really old simulations before this century. Example:

```
module top (
  input [3:0] a, b,
  input       cin,
  output reg       Cout,
  output     [2:0] Ctemp,
  output reg [3:0] sum,
  input clk,
  input X );
```